# mod rewrite not working on prod while perfectly on dev server - add path into postfix missing

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am successfully redirecting on a test system through mod rewrite. Unfortunatelly the "same" production system refuses to redirect within a particular virtualhost. Works for other virtualhosts perfectly. Super strange!

apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost 194.1.10.8:80>
    ServerName m.test
    rewriteEngine On

<Directory ~ "/home/www/test/MEW/">
   RewriteRule  ^testdir/(.*)$ subapp_search/index.php?fa=1&category=$1 [L]
</Directory>

    DocumentRoot /home/www/test/MEW/
```

apache error log file after calling http://m.test/testdir/example:

```
[error] [client 85.181.129.13] File does not exist: /home/www/test/MEW/testdir
```

I believe the rewrite conditions do not apply, since they are inside a directory directive:

```
 <Directory ...
  RewriteCond ...
```

the log file from mod_rewrite shows no intend to "add path into postfix"

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /kleinanzeige/brse-fallingbostel-kragenechse-australische-wasseragame-bis
(1) pass through /kleinanzeige/brse-fallingbostel-kragenechse-aus
```

tralische-wasseragame-bis

on my dev system it does and ads the correct directory to the path /home/www/project/...

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When inside Apache config you must start your pattern in `RewriteRule` with a leading slash, so use:

```
RewriteRule ^/testdir/(.*)$ /subapp_search/index.php?fa=1&category=$1 [L,QSA]
```